# Thanks TWP Community!

Tags: discussion

Just wanted to extend a big "Thanks" to TWP community for a great effort to push us over the goal line to graduation. We came a long way guys, and it would've never been possible without some big contributions from some key members.

Thanks a lot guys! And good luck to all candidates in the upcoming moderator election. This is gonna be a big one. Let's keep everything going in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for the nice sentiment.  Since this isn't actually a question or proposal, and the election has passed, I'm going to close it now.